# View object properties values on selection of Listbox items

Tags: c#

I have a base class, `Item`, and 3 derived classes: `Weapon`, `Shield`, `Armor`.

I've created a listbox and populated it with all three of the derived classes.

My question is, how can I access the properties values of the class when I select it in the list box? I've tried:

```
dynamic weapon = Convert.ChangeType(item, typeof(Weapon));
```

But `weapon` doesn't give me access to the properties values. I see the same intellisense options as if I do:

```
var item = LstStoreItems.SelectedItem;
```

The goal I'm trying to accomplish is selecting an object from the list box, and populating some labels based upon the object selected.

**EXAMPLE**

A `Weapon` has a `Name`, `Attack`, `Type`, and `Cost`. A `Shield` has `Name`, `Defense`, `Material`,  and `Cost`. Whenever I select a `Weapon`, I want to populate labels on my form to display this information to the user. When I select a `Shield`, I want to display that information.

Comment: use reflection: `item.GetType().GetProperties()`. But please do not over-use it, as reflections are **very** slow. For simple task you may also use `if` blocks like `if (item is Weapon) DoThis(); else if (item is Shield) DoThat(); else if (item is Armor) DoThisAndThat(); else DoNothing();`

Comment: Can you give an example what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: What UI framework do you use?

Comment: any reason for using the `dynamic` keyword if you know the type on the right hand side. Also am confused have you tried the `as`/`is` keywords?

Comment: `Convert.ChangeType` returns an object, hence you are not getting the intellisense options. Also for custom type this interface will not work out of the box

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What worked for me in the end is the following:

```
        if (!(LstPlayerItems.SelectedItem is Item item)) return;

        if (item.GetType() == typeof(Weapon) && item is Weapon weapon)
        {
            LblAttDef.Content = weapon.MinimumDamage + " to " + weapon.MaximumDamage;
            LblAttDefLabel.Content = "Attack";
        }
```

This now allows me to reference the `Weapon` properties on the object `weapon` and accomplish what I was trying for.

Comment: `item.GetType() == typeof(Weapon)` is redundant

Answer (score 1):

`if` blocks with method overloading maybe helpful here

```
private void SelectedItemChangedHandler()
{
    var item = LstStoreItems.SelectedItem;

    if (item is Weapon) SetLabelsFor(item as Weapon);
    else if (item is Shield) SetLabelsFor(item as Shield);
    else if (item is Armor) SetLabelsFor(item as Armor);
    else ClearLabels();
}

private void SetLabelsFor(Weapon weapon)
{
    label1.Text = weapon.Name;
    // etc.
}

private void SetLabelsFor(Shield shield)
{
    label1.Text = shield.Name;
    // etc.
}

private void SetLabelsFor(Armor armor)
{
    label1.Text = armor.Name;
    // etc.
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but this approach should be called "F...ck OOP and design patterns". What if there are 10+ `Item` descendants? 10+ `else if`s?

Comment: @Dennis, The question was _"How to set Text property of already existing labels based on selected item value?"_ and I can't see how this approach actualy _"Hugs OOP"_ or any of _"design patterns"_. Anyway, yes, there will be 10+ `else if`s. There is also may be a `switch` block. Or `foreach` loop on reflection of `item` properties. Or any other method you like.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use something like :

```
private void SelectOneItemBasedOnType(){
var selected=TheListBox.SelectedItem;
//Check for example, if the item is a shield.
if(selected is Shield){
Shield shield=(Shield) selected;
MessageBox.Show(shield.cost);
}
//Etc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not confident on what the best approach for this may be. I am picturing a “master-detail” type scenario. It is unclear how “varied” the different inheritors may be, and looping through the properties may be a challenge depending on how “different” they are between the inheritors.

Given this, one possible solution is to make `Item` an abstract class and create an abstract method to “force” the inheritors to implement this. Each inheritor of `Item` will need to implement a `SetItemPropertiesLabels` method. An example of how it may work… let’s say there is a `Panel` next to the `ListBox` of `Items`. This panel holds all the labels that describe the currently selected `Item`. When the list box selection changes, the panels current labels are cleared, then the selected `Items` `SetPanelLabels` method is called. There the labels and text for the `Item` properties are set on the panel. Then the “required” `SetItemPropertiesLabels(panel)` method is called to add the selected items individual properties.

Using this approach, the `SelectedIndexChanged` event may look something like…

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  Item selectedItem = (Item)listBox1.SelectedItem;
  ItemPanel.Controls.Clear();
  selectedItem.SetPanelLabels(ItemPanel);
}
```

Item Class

```
public abstract class Item {
  public string ItemName { get; set; }
  public string Cost { get; set; }

  public Item() {
    ItemName = "";
  }

  public Item(string itemName, string cost) {
    ItemName = itemName;
    Cost = cost;
  }

  public void SetPanelLabels(Panel panel) {
    Label lbl = new Label();
    lbl.AutoSize = true;
    lbl.Text = "Item Name: " + ItemName + "   Cost: " + Cost;
    lbl.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(10, 10);
    panel.Controls.Add(lbl);
    SetItemPropertiesLabels(panel);
  }

  // This is the method that all inheritors must implement.
  public abstract void SetItemPropertiesLabels(Panel panel);
}
```

Armour class

```
class Armour : Item {
  public string Type { get; set; }
  public string Material { get; set; }

  public Armour() {
  }

  public Armour(string itemName, string cost) : base(itemName, cost) {
  }

  public override void SetItemPropertiesLabels(Panel panel) {
    Label lbl = new Label();
    lbl.AutoSize = true;
    lbl.Text = "Armour Type: " + Type + "  Material: " + Material;
    lbl.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(15, 50);
    panel.Controls.Add(lbl);
  }
}
```

Shield Class

```
class Shield : Item {
  public string Defense { get; set; }
  public string Material { get; set; }

  public Shield(string itemName, string cost) : base(itemName, cost) {
  }

  public override void SetItemPropertiesLabels(Panel panel) {
    Label lbl = new Label();
    lbl.AutoSize = true;
    lbl.Text = "Shield Defense: " + Defense + "  Material: " + Material;
    lbl.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(15, 50);
    panel.Controls.Add(lbl);
  }
}
```

Weapon class

```
class Weapon : Item {

  public string Attack { get; set; }
  public string Type { get; set; }

  public Weapon() {
  }

  public Weapon(string itemName, string cost) : base(itemName, cost) {
  }

  public override void SetItemPropertiesLabels(Panel panel) {
    Label lbl = new Label();
    lbl.AutoSize = true;
    lbl.Text = "Weapon Type: " + Type + "  Attack: " + Attack;
    lbl.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(15, 50);
    panel.Controls.Add(lbl);
  }
}
```

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: I guess this might be the most elegant solution other than putting 100s of `if else` blocks. It will violate MVVM completely but I am guessing OP is not concerned with it.